# persistence database (cache) java

Tags: java, database, performance, caching, nosql

I got database warehouse where i store all important data for last year (huge amount of data). Amount of data, which i write to that database, depends on day time. The problem is that during rush hours my application became really slow, because of inserting data to database. My idea is to make a persistencedatabase (or cache) for keeping data, before inserting it to db warehouse. Can you please suggest technologies for this idea? Should i use nosql or cache? (app is written in java, db is mysql)

Comment: also i dont have a lot of rams ( ideal no more than 256 mb)

Comment: 256mb of RAM is probably not enough for putting "huge amount of data from last year" in a DB. Look into Redis, tho..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use distributed caching to solve your problem. The way you can use distributed caching would be to use **Read through/Write-Behind**

What **Read through/Write-Behind** means is:
 
`This is where the application treats cache as the main data store and reads data from it and writes data to it. The cache is responsible for reading and writing this data to the database, thereby relieving the application of this responsibility.`

What this means is that your application will always try to read say **key X** from cache. If **key X** is found in cache then great ! Return the value associated with X. If key is not found in cache then query the underlying database, update the cache and return data. This is **Read through**

In the **Write-Behind** scenario, modified cache entries are asynchronously written to the data source after a configurable delay, whether after 10 seconds, 20 minutes, a day or even a week or longer. For Write-Behind caching, we could maintain a write-behind queue of the data that must be updated in the data source. When the application updates X in the cache, X is added to the write-behind queue (if it isn't there already; otherwise, it is replaced), and after the specified write-behind delay we could call the CacheStore to update the underlying data source with the latest state of X. Note that the write-behind delay is relative to the first of a series of modifications—in other words, the data in the data source will never lag behind the cache by more than the write-behind delay.

More details on above refer [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13924_01/coh.340/e13819/readthrough.htm)

There are other distributed caching techniques mentioned in the above doc as well. Read it and pick the ones which match your use case the best. To answer second part of your question, you could **redis** cache as your cache system choice.